# Using ternary operator for Funcs of the same type needs casting

Tags: c#, casting, ternary-operator

I have this issue:

```
Func<string,string> transformer = isRTF ? ToRTF : ToHTML;

private string ToRTF(string value) {
    //Convert to RTF 
    return value;        
}
private string ToHTML(string value) {
    //Convert to HTML
    return value;    
}
```

However I am getting this error:

> Error  42  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'

However if I do this:

```
Func<string, string> transformer = isRTF ? (Func<string, string>) ToRTF : (Func<string, string>) ToHTML;
```

it works without problems and ReSharper starts complaining that the cast is redundant.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You only need one of the casts.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly why it's happening...

Comment: The supposed duplicate does not explain this problem, only provides a solution that OP already knows. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Don't know if it's the reason ReSharper warns about it, but as Lee mentioned: you only need one cast, the other part of the ternary operator will revert to the type of the other if it can: `Func<string,string> transformer = isRTF ? (Func<string, string>) ToRTF : ToHTML;` or to prevent double declaration of the type, you can even use  `var transformer = isRTF ? (Func<string, string>) ToRTF : ToHTML;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because both sides need a conversion from method group<sup>*</sup> to `Func<string,string>`. The compiler has rules to infer the type of one method group from the type given to the other method group, but no rules for situations when both sides of `:` have method groups.

You can do the conversion only on one side, and let the compiler infer the other side for you. You can also use `var` for the declaration to avoid repeating the type:

```
var transformer = isRTF ? new Func<string,string>(ToRTF) : ToHTML;
```

<sup>*</sup> Method name used in implicit definitions of delegates are treated as method groups, because a single name can represent multiple overloaded methods.

Comment: You should add the fact why we get a method group type here (because of possible overloaded methods). That would answer the why better

Comment: I feel a bit silly now. It seems obvious once someone points it out. My `ToHTML` method was not really a Func but actually a generic method group (if I understand this correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is answered and I think the answer is quite good and correct. Nevertheless I encountered this same problem a while ago and what I did to work around this was to return Func from the method itself. Like the following:

```
 private static Func<string,string> A() => (v) => string.Empty;

 private static Func<string,string> B() => (v) => "I am not empty =)";
```

And:

```
var myFunc = someBool ? A() : B();
```

I know that this will require to change method's signature and that do not solves the issue directly but at least you do not need to cast.

Hope this helps